# Can't scrape dynamic span tag without selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I want to scrape a news portal(link in my code), but I'm not just scrape the title and article in there, I want to scrape the article author, date, etc. Mostly works just using `BeautifulSoup`, but not the total comment inside the article.

So this is my code. The string I added on link is to made the page display full article(if not I will face pagination, which is more time consumed when scraping):

```
lnk = ('https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5297980/pemprov-dki-tegaskan-aturan-wfh-75-juga-berlaku-untuk-perusahaan-swasta')
lnk2 = lnk + '?single=1'
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(resp2, 'lxml')
element = soup2.find('span', text=re.compile('komentar')).text
print(element)
comment = element.text.rstrip(' komentar')
```

And this is part of html page I want to scrape:
[image]

With my code above I can scrape it, but always result '0' even like the picture above shows '25'. Until now the problem I encountered is it must be using 'wait' method so the page can loaded and the truly number can be scraped.

I already tried using `Selenium WebDriverWait`, this is the code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(lnk2)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")

html = driver.page_source
beau = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')
element = beau.find_element_by_css_selector('a.komentar > span')
WebDriverWait(soup2, 10).until(lambda driver: element.text != '0 komentar')
comment = element.text.rstrip(' komentar')
```

But maybe all of you know already, `Selenium` weakness is really consume time. My scraper can scrape about 200 news article page in news portal above(with data like date, etc but without total comment) with about 0.25 sec/page, or 3 min/200 page. But if I add that `WebDriverWait` JUST for the total comment, it will take about 15 sec/page, or 49 min/200 page. Really different.

So my question is there any way to get that dynamic span tag without `Selenium`, and not make scraping time less efficient(maybe it will cost more time, but not like 0.25 sec to 15 sec)? Or maybe using `Selenium` but you guys know the trick how to make it more efficient.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If content is dynamically added to the DOM with javascript, you will not be able to get this content with beautifulsoup because a javacript function is adding it to the page after the http response is returned.

Comment: So is there any way instead using `Selenium WebDriverWait`?